# Only support for landscape Interface orientation

Tags: iphone, landscape

I have application that uses landscape right orientation.
In view controllers I use:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  // Return YES for supported orientations
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

But, If user **locks** iphone or ipad to **portrait** orientation, screen is displayed
as portrait, not landscape. Also, in info.plist file I defined only **Right Landscape** orientation as
supported one.

Comment: Note that there are two types of Landscape orientations: Left and Right.

Comment: Indeed, change your code to return `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape(interfaceOrientation)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in function viewDidLoad where another view controller is pushed into navigation stack immediately. If pushing action is delayed then landscape rotation will start and proceed, and also desired view controller will be pushed properly with landscape orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `UIInterfaceOrientation` key in your Info.plist to `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`. That should force landscape right orientation on launch.

Comment: I already set it. But it doesn't help when iphone is locked in portrait.