# Forcing rotation to landscape

Tags: iphone, uiview, autorotate

I would like my app's rotation to be fixed as landscape...

I've done some research, but most posts are about detecting change,

and I couldn't find any about forcing one.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

In plist change the Supported interface orientations to Lansdscape

OR

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); // home button on right
}
```

All the best

Answer (score 1):

You can change the info.plist of your project so that you app always shows Landscape initially.And then you can make your view controller's to support only landscape orientation.

hope this also helps

[Only support for landscape Interface orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293861/only-support-for-landscape-interface-orientation)

[Launching application in landscape orientation for IPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947501/launching-application-in-landscape-orientation-for-ipad)