# Disable portrait mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, landscape

I am developing an iPhone application and the application should work only in landscape mode. But, when I rotate the device or simulator, the viewContoller's mode changes from landscape to portrait. I want the viewController to maintain in landscape mode, though the device or simulator is portrait. How could I make this happen? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override this method in your view controller:

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientation, NO for other;
}
```

Comment: The OP states that he doesn't want support for portrait mode, so just returning YES won't help.

Comment: Obviously... I just pointed the method he has to override. I did not write the full code...

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `ViewController.m`

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change in info_plist ..
Supported interface orientations     Set only landscape

Comment: i have this set, but it doesn't seem to be enough.

Answer (score -1):

Override this method in all your ViewControllers:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ||
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
```

}

And also see [Only support for landscape Interface orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293861/only-support-for-landscape-interface-orientation)